# Different redirect page for registration, login and first time login

Tags: redirection, users

Im trying to redirect the user to different pages on login, first-time login and registration. I used the Login Destination module but it only has the option to redirect the user to one page on registration login and first-time login. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this but from the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1280858) page:

> There are no separate triggers for login and registration; instead you
>   can differentiate them by specifying the pages that a user comes from:
>
> - user - the user login form.
> - user/register - the user registration form.
> - user/*/edit - one-time login link, after the user has set the password.
> - other - the login block or login forms embedded by other    modules.

It looks like you can specify both three options you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach:
 - create a simple module, implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7):

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // dpm($form_id);
  // dpm($form);
  if ('user_register_form' == $form_id) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_register_callback';
  }
}

function my_custom_register_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // do some logic, redirect;
}

function MYMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if (null == $account->access /* this user has not been logged in before, he/she is being logged in the first time */) {
    // redirect him/her, eg. drupal_goto('SOME_URL');
  }
  else {
    // redirect him/her to another URL;
  }
}
```